# OR operator in react native

Tags: react-native, or-operator

I wonder if the react native can read the `||` operator in the condition. I'm trying to do some data filtering in my app where either one of the data is true and so I used the `||` operator. But then, my app seems not be able to read it.

Example :

```
if(this.state.open_intro == false || this.state.intro.length < 0){
  // do some statement at here
} else {
  // do some statement at here
}
```

My `this.state.open_intro` is `false` and the value of `this.state.intro.length` is more than 0 though. So it supposed to read the else statement, but it always read the first statement.

Comment: That's how or operator works. Only one statement needs to be true.

Answer (score 0):

a=1;
b=2;

```
if(a == 10 || b == 1) 

{ This is correct logic }

 else

{ This is incorrect logic };
```